# .htaccess file not allowing POST functions to process

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server

I created an htaccess file that I saw on a tutorial. My main goal was to remove the .php at the end of the file names in my browser. This worked perfectly. However, I am running into some major issues since I have created this.

1. Anything that has a method of POST will not process. It just reloads the current page, but does nothing.
2. When I try to log in, it redirects me to my home page. Then when I go back to the signin page, it allows me to log in.
3. My font-awesome images are no longer displaying.

Issue 1 and 2 are definitely the most important issues that need resolved. I've been stuck on this for days and cannot find anything that resolves this.

This is what I currently have that loads my pages fine, except for the issues I mentioned.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^er$ er.png [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

This last part ^^ is one thing I tried to add to make the POST's work. It did nothing. It is positioned in the file just as I posted it in here.

I also tried using the following that someone created for me, but it doesn't even allow me to get on my site.

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite/$1 [R,L]

# allow cross origin fonts
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

# allow php files to respond without extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# remove php extension if provided
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\\.php [L]
```

I have all of my POST methods directing like the following.

```
action="/index"
```

Comment: Are you using Absolute url or Relative url for navigation?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by that. Do you mean the meta url tag? if so I have this <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">

Comment: No I mean to say how are you linking your pages  '<a href=" URL  "></a>' and naming <form action = " URL ">

Comment: I'm linking my pages like this, but I can't even get on my main index page.  <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute URL for e.g. `http://localhost/yourwebsite/products` in all `<a href="">` and `<form action="">`.

Comment: Wouldn't the page not reload then? Say if I was adding a product and wanted it to direct me right to the shopping cart, wouldn't this method leave me on the current page?

Comment: No it wont. `header('location: http://localhost/yourwebsite/cart/')` ... Once you use absolute URL ... you should use it for everything ... Linking CSS, Images etc.